# Mounting a stream encoder as a drive in windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, device-driver

For a variety of reasons, revolving around cost of copy and the travails of the Windows filesystem, I need to mount a stream encoder as a drive, so that incoming data can simply be blindly directed at this "drive", aggregated, and encoded, without the source program being any the wiser. This would be basically trivial on Linux, but seems to be an uphill struggle on windows.

Specifically, I'd like to be able to "mount" a tar builder, which I know sounds odd, but there's a compelling reason for doing this. Is there a utility or library that deals with this? Perhaps an obscure part of the Windows API?

[This looks promising...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it seems intended to mount folders or similar, rather than "devices." I do have control of where the data is written, so I can specify an arbitrary path.

Comment: you need to be more specific... what is it you want to mount ? a device ? a folder ? what protocol ? FTP ? SFTP ? HTTP ? HTTPS ? SMB ? NFS ?

Comment: In general, I really do want to be able to mount an arbitrary program that accepts as input a stream and outputs a transform of that stream. In actuality, I want to be able to direct output to a tar builder that accepts a stream

Comment: And yes, I grok that this is likely to consume unspeakable amounts of ram as "writes" pile up. That's okay.

Comment: I am still not sure because "mount" means something different (at least on Windows or just to me?)... Windows has the ability to accept a stream as stdin and output things on stdout - is this what you ask about ?

Comment: Impossible as written, I think; drives are block devices, and data is written unpredictably to different blocks, so redirecting the data to a stream device would be meaningless.  Do you mean you want to capture the data being written to a particular file or files as a stream?  Can you control the name of the file(s) the data is being written to?

Comment: Would a RAM drive solve your problem?  Once the data had been written you could then forward it to the target program?

Comment: Incidentally, DefineDosDevice might be used by a solution but definitely isn't a solution itself.  It allows you to assign drive letters to existing devices but (despite the name) doesn't actually create devices itself.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is impossible as written. I came to the same conclusion last night, an have opted to use a RAMdrive. I've 64 gigs of ram to blow after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having experience with virtual drives (see our Virtual Storage product line) I can say that your task needs some redefining. As said in comments, drives (or, better say, filesystems) in Windows are expected to be namely filesystems (unlike Unix world), and as such they must support certain reading and enumeration operations, which is not something you'd expect.

Probably the closest you can do is a virtual drive in memory whose contents are then passed to your application in some way. The user will drag the data to your drive and on unmounting (or on other command) drive contents are passed to other program.

Several of our products can be used for your task (see CallbackDisk, Callback File System and SolFS OS Edition on [Virtual Storage](http://www.eldos.com/virtual-storage/) page), yet they are all commercial products. If you have a one-time or short-term task, you can build something for your use with a trial key.

There exist free approaches to your task, namely Pismo File Mount and Dokan, but I don't know how well they fit.